# How can I easily generate a list of symbols with static storage?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, static

We have a large C++ project that we're building with both GCC and MSVC, and we've encountered the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order). Is there a way to generate a list of symbols that take part in static initialization so I can generate a plan to resolve the problem?

I've created a map file from both GCC and MSVC. MSVC's output didn't look very useful. It appears that GCC's map file could be used - I extracted everything related to the `bss` section. However, many of the symbols come from libraries and just add noise to the information.

Is there a trick or some other convenient way to obtain the information I'm looking for (short of reading every source file manually)?

Answer (score 1):

For Visual C++:  Sort the lines of the .map file.  This will ensure the symbols are ordered by address.

Search for symbols `__xc_a` and `__xc_z`.  The symbols that appear *between* those two symbols are all of the dynamic initializers for objects with static storage duration.  The initializers will be executed in the order they appear in the list.

Each entry in the .map file includes both

1. the name of the global variable (e.g., the initializer for global variable `fred` will be `fred$initializer$`, plus the required C++ name decoration), and
2. the object file that contained the global variable (e.g. `fred.obj`).  If the symbol came from a static library, the static library will be listed (e.g. `libfred:fred.obj`).

(I don't know enough about GCC to answer how to do this with their tools.)

Comment: GCC is complex, because of it's roots as a "replacement C compiler" - neither a true C++ compiler nor a full C compiler. In particular, it accounts for quite a few different Standard Library implementations (either the GNU C library) which usually are shipped with the OS, not GCC itself. As a result, GCC implements `main` in different ways, and this also affects how ctors are run. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564078/why-does-gcc-put-calls-to-constructors-of-global-instances-into-different-sectio