# Cannot add content to "ctors" section with linker

Tags: assembly, linker, alpine-linux, gnu-assembler, static-constructor

I have a project where I am loading a shared object into a Go application. This shared object has static constructors. It works on Ubuntu and Centos, but not in Alpine where static constructors are not called because of incompatibility between musl-libc and Go runtime. GCC puts static constructors (like `__attribute__((constructor))`) into `.init_array` which is called by the loader in glibc, but not by musl-libc who leaves this to the C start-up code. In case of Go runtime does not implement these calls to the functions in `.init_array`.

On the other hand, on both cases the loader calls the functions in `.ctors` section. It looks like an ideal solution for this project.

I am trying to add my constructors (C or ASM) to the `.ctors` section, but after linking my shared object they seem to be moved to `.init_array` by the linker (ld).

Here is my example ASM code:

```
       .intel_syntax noprefix
       .text

       .section      .rodata
.Message:
       .string "Constructor called!"

       .text
Constructor:
       lea    rdi, .Message[rip]
       jmp    puts@PLT

       .section      .ctors,"a"
__CTOR_LIST__:
       .quad  Constructor
```

I run compile and link it but the `.ctors` logically empty!

```
$ gcc ctors.s -c -o ctors.o
$ ld -shared ctors.o -o ctors.so
$ readelf -x 14 /libctors.so 
Hex dump of section '.ctors':
  0x00003df8 ffffffff ffffffff 00000000 00000000 ................
```

Why is this happening? Can make my array stay in `.ctors` section? How can I add functions to the `.ctors` sections?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564078/why-does-gcc-put-calls-to-constructors-of-global-instances-into-different-sectio https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46770 i think the best way for you is to configure gcc with --disable-initfini-array